# Symfony create global Class only for Datatype C-like struct

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I am currently developing an APP in Symfony 6.1.
I have a always same Set of data, which is using always the same format. For this I want to create a class, which generates Objects using this structure.
This class should be globally available (like a Symfony Service) but allow to create as many Instances as I want to. Symfony Services as far as I know, only create one Instance while Autowiring.
What is the best way to do this in Symfony, without messing with the intended Symfony style?

```
class MyDatatype {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
}
```

Comment: You could create a method within your class that returns a new instance of itself `return new self();` for example, that way you can autowire as normal and then call that method anytime you would like to create a new instance..

Comment: All classes in PHP are globally available, Symfony places no restriction on that, nor could it. If you don’t want it to participate in autowiring, don’t use it in that context. At any given moment you can call `new XYX` and pass it to another method/function that requires an `XYZ`